# ASP.NET MVC Action Method Periodically Not Receiving GET parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with default routing.

When I navigate to the following page:

```
/Portfolio/Company?id=12345
```

My action method (below) correctly picks up the id parameter and the method is able to execute successfully:

```
public ActionResult Company(long id)
{
  <do things with the id>
}
```

Somewhat frequently, when a user visits the same exact URL, the id ("12345" in the example above) is NOT correctly getting passed to the Company method.  This causes the method to fail with:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Company(Int64)' in
>   'PortfolioController'. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

This makes me think they are visiting the URL with no id value specified.

I am not able to reproduce this problem for myself. In the logs, I correctly see the users navigating to the page with a valid id parameter being passed in the URL.  The users also state they never see an error appear on screen, the error message above I only see in the logs.

I'm stuck as to what can be happening - the users notice no issue with website and they appear to be using the correct URLs, but I keep having errors fire on the backend.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add code that dumps the contents of the parameters dictionary when it happens. See what's in there instead of `id`.

Comment: Do you have splunk logging integration in your application? If yes, some of such error would be reported in the logs.

Comment: Is your application publicly accessible? If so, you might see webcrawlers trying to access /Portfolio/Company without the id parameter.

Comment: Try loading the page with Chrome dev tools or the like and see if there are any other requests firing that return a 500 error. Maybe something else on your page is making the invalid request. It could even be something weird like a CSS or script load.